# Keyboards plugged to one computer have different failing rows of keys, but work perfectly fine on any other computer

Tags: usb, keyboard, ps2

I have a PS2 and an USB keyboard. Recently, a column of keys on my PS2 keyboard failed, so I swapped it for an USB keyboard, but that one turned out to have another different failing column of keys. Both keyboards work fine when I plug them on another machine. What's wrong with my computer?

Comment: When you say "column of keys", what are the actual sets of keys that fail in each case?  In what way do they fail (e.g., no response? wrong output?)?  Does any keyboard work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

now this is hard. i think it has got to be the software/drivers on your computer. plug in one of your keyboards, then right click my computer (or This PC) and choose 'manage' you will need administrator privileges. on the left collumn, click on 'device manager'. then on the right, right click 'keyboard and choose 'scan for hardware changes'. if nothing shows up (except for the plug and play window that pops up and then disappear after it finishes), expand 'keyboard' . look for the keyboard you are having issues with. then right click it and choose 'properties'. in the 'drivers' tab of the new window, look for 'roll back driver'. press it and wait for windows to roll back to a previous version of the driver. you might have to restart your computer. if the 'roll back driver' box is greyed out, it means that your computer doesn't have a previous version of the keyboard's driver to roll back to. in that case (or if rolling back driver didn't help you), click on 'update driver' you might not need to restart your computer but i am not sure. see if that helps you. try doing this for both keyboards. if you don't know which driver is your keyboard's, or encounter any problem, or that what i told didn't help you, take a screenshot (how to take screenshot: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/screenshot.xml   if you are on a laptop, you will need to hold the fn key while pressing 'prt sc'-print screen or home) and post it in the comment to this reply.